# Prove that a set has cardinality continuum

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The task is to prove that set of bijections between set of natural numbers is continuum(is equinumerous to the set of real numbers).
I have some ideas, like proving that mentioned set is equinumerous  to the set of points in section from 0 to 1, however hasn’t really managed that

Comment: I’ve been also thinking about trying to find bijection between mentioned set and set of 0/1 infinite sequences, however that only may show that mentioned set is not less than continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a subset of $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ which has size continuum, so your set has size $\le \mathfrak{c}$.

To see it has at least that size, find a bijection from the set of bijections onto the set  $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ of $0$-$1$-sequences: one idea is to map $f$ to the sequence $(a_n)_n$ defined by $a_n = \frac{1}{2}(1 - (-1)^{n + f(n)})$, or in words: if $n$ and $f(n)$ have the same parity $a_n=0$, otherwise $a_n=1$. All sequences can occur as images (try to prove that) so we have a surjection onto a set of size continuum, making your set of size $\ge \mathfrak{c}$. Cantor-Bernstein does the rest. Or be creative and come up with an easier surjection than mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that.

Comment: Wouldn't the altenating sequence $b_n = (1+(-1)^n)/2$ fail to be in the image?  It seems a sequence $a$ is in the image if and only if $a_n+b_n -2a_nb_n$ takes on each of $0, 1$ infinitely often.  Of course, this would mean there are only countably many sequences not in the image, so even if I'm correct, it should be simple to fix.